# How do I access the elements of an array passed as a double-pointer?

Tags: c++

This is the prototype for the function, `sum`, I am using to summate the elements of two arbitrary arrays.

```
double **sum(double **A, double **B, int M, int N);
```

They're both passed as double-pointers (don't ask why) and `M` and `N` are supposed to be the dimensions of the arrays respectively.

What I'm having trouble doing is, within the implementation of the function, accessing elements of the arrays. I've tried "deferencing" the array (or so I think) but to no avail. Below are the things I've tried:

```
> *A;  // Gives me an address, 0xf5c28f5c, not a number
> **A; // Error
> &A;  // Gives me the address of A
```

This is how I'm passing the arrays to `sum` if it's helpful:

```
double a[] = {5.34, 5.23, 6.5, 3.51};
double b[] = {74.3, 42.1, 642.2, 54.2};

sum( (double **) a, (double **) b, 4, 4);
```

So the question is, how exactly am I supposed to get the elements in the arrays when passed by pointer/double-pointer?

Comment: You don't want us to ask why you use double-pointers, so I won't ask. But still, it is wrong. Your arrays are not double-pointers, so you shouldn't force them to be.

Comment: Also tag this as homework because, well it is homework. faculty.capitol-college.edu/~conner/230p1.doc

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm afraid it's not if you're referring to me...

Comment: An array is not a pointer.  **An array is not a pointer**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array passage to your function is entirely incorrect. A double pointer is best to be thought of as a pointer-to-pointer. In the same way a pointer is a variable that holds the address to memory someplace, a pointer-to-pointer holds a similar address, it just so happens the memory it references is the memory occupied by another pointer. This is best described by example:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    int *p = &a;
    int **pp = &p;
    printf("pp=%p, &p=%p, p=%p, &a=%p *p=%d\n", pp, &p, p, &a, *p);
    return 0;
}
```

On my MBA 64bit, this give us:

```
pp=0x7fff50828bc8, &p=0x7fff50828bc8, p=0x7fff50828bd4, &a=0x7fff50828bd4 *p=5
```

Get a grasp on that and I think you'll find your issues in your code, the first of which is the hard cast to a double pointer of 'a' and 'b'. Maybe try their addresses instead. Secondly, you will likely want to revisit how you're using those pointers for dereferences in your function, because chances are that needs work too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't in retrieving values from the `double**` when inside the function, that's trivial. The problem is you're creating an **array** and not a set of pointers. Your function can't accept this as an argument, and when you try to cast with `(double**)` the `A` argument will cause an access violation when accessed like a `**`.

```
double** sum(double** A, int size)
{
  printf("First element: %f", A[0][0]); // Print the first element      
  printf("Last element: %f", A[size-1][size-1]); // Print the last element.
  return A;
}


const unsigned int SIZE = 4;
double** a = new double*[SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
  a[i] = new double[SIZE];
}

a = sum(a, SIZE);
```

The biggest pain working with pointers like this (and not containers, specially designed to handle these situations..) is you memory management is likely to get out of hand.

```
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
  delete [] a[i]; // Free the inner array
}
delete [] a; // Free the outer array.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function takes a pointer to pointer to `double`, and you begin with an actual array, then you'll need to make a copy of the address of the array, and then pass a reference to that:

```
double a[] = {5.34, 5.23, 6.5, 3.51};
double b[] = {74.3, 42.1, 642.2, 54.2};

double *aPtr = a;
double *bPtr = b;
sum(&aPtr, &bbtr, 4, 4);
```

In the `sum` function, de-reference to get back to the arrays: `*A[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution would be to pass the arrays as pointers, rather than as double-pointers:

```
double sum(double *A, double *B, int M, int N)
{
   double ret = 0.0;
   for (int i=0; i<M; i++) ret += A[i];
   for (int j=0; j<N; j++) ret += B[j];
   return ret;
}

double a[] = {5.34, 5.23, 6.5, 3.51};
double b[] = {74.3, 42.1, 642.2, 54.2};
double s = sum( a, b, 4, 4);
printf("The sum is %f\n", s);
```

... doing that would be the simplest thing.  However, if you're constrained by an existing API to a function-signature that uses double-pointers, that might be because the API wants to allow the called function to be able to modify the pointers that were passed in to it.  Passing a pointer-to-a-pointer allows the called function to write to the pointed-to-pointer if it wants to, e.g:

```
double sum_and_change_pointers(double ** A, double ** B, int M, int N)
{
   // Compute sum
   double ret = 0.0;
   for (int i=0; i<M; i++) ret += (*A)[i];
   for (int j=0; j<N; j++) ret += (*B)[j];

   // And just for fun, modify the caller's pointer-values too
   static double some_other_array[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
   *A = some_other_array;
   *B = some_other_array;

   return ret;
}
```

In such a scenario, the function would be called like this:

```
double a[] = {5.34, 5.23, 6.5, 3.51};
double b[] = {74.3, 42.1, 642.2, 54.2};
double * pa = a;  // copy address of arrays into pointers
double * pb = b;  // because changing the address of an array itself wouldn't work
printf("Before calling sum_and_change_pointers, pa=%p and pb=%p\n", pa, pb);
double s = sum_and_change_pointers( &pa, &pb, 4, 4);
printf("After calling sum_and_change_pointers, s=%f, pa=%p and pb=%p\n", s, pa, pb);
```

Another note:  in your posted code you have your function returning a (double**) rather than a double.  I don't think that can easily work; first of all, a function named sum is presumably returning a double-precision floating point value, not a pointer-to-a-pointer, so it doesn't make sense to have it return a (double**)... but even if you did (for some reason) want to do it that way, you'd need to make sure the pointer-to-a-pointer you returned was pointing to a valid location in memory (and that that location was pointing to a valid location in memory too), which is tricky to do from inside a function, since all of the function's local variables go away when the function returns.  I suppose you could do it with a static or global variable if you didn't mind losing thread-safety:

```
double ** sub (double ** A, double ** B, int M, int N)
{
   // Compute sum
   double ret = 0.0;
   for (int i=0; i<M; i++) ret += (*A)[i];
   for (int j=0; j<N; j++) ret += (*B)[j];

   static double result;
   result = ret;

   static double * pointerToResult;
   pointerToResult = &ret;
   return &pointerToResult;
}

[...]
double ** s = sum( a, b, 4, 4);
printf("Sum's result was %f\n", **s);
```

... but again, this is ugly, unsafe, and unhelpful to actually do.  Much better to use the correct types for the job you want to do.